# Custom Windows workflows with inforpath task forms-Switching Multiple views in same form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, workflow-foundation, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

I am customizing a developed windows workflow by adding more views to the task form. And in Workflow.xml there are task forms defined as "Task0_FormURN,Task1_FormURN,Task2_FormURN,Task3_FormURN,Task4_FormURN,Task5_FormURN" (Tags were Removed here). And each of these forms works fine with current workflow.

But when I add a new view and increment the form as "Task6_FormURN" in workflow xml and set the "TaskType" property as "6" in the code behind of the workflowproperies it only shows the default view. The currently added view is not shown as the next form rather it shows the default view.

I already published and deployed the inforpath form and it is correctly updated in the central administration inforpath templates folder as well.I used Sharepoint 2007, Visual Studio 2008,Inforpath 2007.

Is there any configuration to be done in the Inforpath form to view the newly added view? 
How can I get the connection between workflow and Inforpath view other than these?

Great Help Friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via a Rule. The Rule can be specified in the inforpath form Options section.

`Form Options -> Open and Save ->Rules` Section you can Define a rule to Switch Views depending on the TaskType.

Hope this will help you.